# Sling servlet bound to resource Type OSGi R6 annotations does not work

Tags: aem, apache-felix, sling, aem-6

I want to register a servlet to my main base page resource type, such that when the same page is hit with a selector and extension my servlet should be chosen instead of normal page rendering.

I am able to achieve this behaviour easily using the old SCR annotations. See working code below.

```
@Component(metatype = false)
@Service({ javax.servlet.Servlet.class,
        org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.class })
@Properties({
        @Property(name = "sling.servlet.resourceTypes", value = "project/project-foundation/components/structure/page"),
        @Property(name = "sling.servlet.selectors", value = {"info"}),
        @Property(name = "sling.servlet.extensions", value = "js"),
        @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "GET"),
        @Property(name = "service.description", value = "Products Servlet") })
```

Now I want to do this using OSGi R6 annotations, below is the annotations I am using

```
@Component(service = Servlet.class, property = { 
        "sling.servlet.selectors=info",
        "sling.servlet.extensions=js",
        "sling.servlet.methods="+ HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
        "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=project/project-foundation/components/structure/page"
})
```

When I hit the page /en-us/fun-games.info.js, my servlet should get called which for now is printing hello world string.(If called)

This servlet is not being picked by when I hit the above URL with selector = info and extension = js when I am using OSGi R6 annotations.

BUT this works with old SCR annotations. I've checked my servlet is being registered properly.

Not sure what is going on.

NOTE: I am using AEM 6.5

I referred this [Link for OSGi R6](http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2017/05/osgi-declarative-services-annotations-in-aem)

Comment: Have you also updated your pom.xml to use `maven-bundle-plugin` version 3.2.0 or greater. The OSGi R6 annotations require it.

Comment: Hi @rakhi4110 My maven-bundle-plugin version is 
`<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.0</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                </plugin>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My God, this was tougher than I thought.

I resolved this using OSGi R7 annotation. I had no idea they existed and AEM supports it.

```
@Component(immediate = true,service = { Servlet.class })
@SlingServletResourceTypes(
    resourceTypes="project/project-foundation/components/structure/page", 
    methods= "GET",
    selectors={ "info", "js"})
```

Also another thing to note is that I used "js" as a selector not extension.

I invoked the page this way 
/en-us/fun-games/mario.info.js

The same servlet can be called on full or shortened URL it does not matter.

And there is one dependency:

```
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.servlets.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
          </dependency>
```

The official documentation I referred to was, [OSGi R7 Anoted Servlets](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting the servlet while giving JCR content in the path like:

```
en-us/fun-games/_jcr_content.info.js
```

I faced the same issue but when I gave the JCR content in the path, it worked.